# What is the type of indexed a type param whitch extends a object

Tags: typescript

```js
type S = {x: 'abc'}
function f<T extends S>() {
  const x: {[k in T['x']]: number} = {abc: 1} // error
  const y: {[k in S['x']]: number} = {abc: 1}
}
function f1<T extends S>() {
  const x: T['x'] = 'abc'
  const y: T['x'] = 'haha' // error
}
```

The first line of function f has a compile error which confuses me:

```js
1. Type '{ abc: number; }' is not assignable to type '{ [k in T["x"]]: number; }'.
     Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'abc' does not exist in type '{ [k in T["x"]]: number; }'.
```

I think `T['x']` is 'abc', so the second line of function f1 has error.
I think the type of x in f should be `{abc: number}` and no compile error

Answer (score 0):

`T['x']` is not `'abc'` because you can define a more restrictive type that extends S:

```js
interface Never extends S {
  x: never;
}
```

Here `Never['x']` is `never`. And that's why `T['x']` is not always `'abc'`.

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAylC8UDeAPAXFA5AQwEYGNMBfAKAEsA7YCAJwDNt9oA5CAN1qghWooBMAzrGQkoUdFArtaAbhKkSdAK4V8wMgHsKUOgB4AKlx4R%20QmAD4AFAEoRY-FoHBxGJAG0A1lEpR9bzCiYALpBGBRKALa4tEQIyHj4GACMsQD0qVw0NBo0olDpYoVFxQB6APx5DhROUCCunt7aMP6BIWGR0TSxiEgJyaQKyqrqWjpJBka8grBWtkiVjs4SfgHBcTgEmAvVznW%20LWuImAAW2KeY%20Rm02blEQA)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But why `const x: T['x'] = 'abc'` has no error? What is `T['x']`?

Comment: Because `T['x']` can be either `'abc'` or `never` and `'abc' | never`, which simplifies to `'abc'` ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggRgYygXigcgIaLVAPlAOwgDcIAnAbgCgB6GqBgPQH4g))

Comment: `never` is useless in union, `'abc' | never` is exactly `'abc'`.